# Build connection to SQL server DB without ODBC driver

Tags: python, azure-sql-database, jupyter, pyodbc

I'm working in restricted environment where I can install only conda supported libraries/packages. I'm trying to build connection to Sql server DB(Azure) via python which requires ODBC driver. Is there any alternate way to build connection to DB without driver?

Comment: If you can use java then you can use jdbc.

Comment: Its a python restricted env only. Can't use java

Comment: Have you tried using pymssql? i use mac m1 which didn't support odbc but i have been using pymssql since and its working fine.

Comment: It requires freeTDS driver. Even that I can't able to install as it is out of conda support. I'm using ubuntu machine

Comment: Do you need to write or only read? If only read you could use html requests to an apache server if you can set one up server side?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately **No**.

ODBC and JDBC are the standard and recommended drivers to connect your Azure SQL Database with backend development.

When it comes to python, `pyodbc` is the standard python library which runs on ODBC Driver to connect with python.